# sssd allow login with both short and log domain credentials

Tags: active-directory, domain

I've setup ubuntu 16.04 to authenticate to active directory using realmd according [to the azure instructions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-rhel-linux-vm/)

I find that I can login as `bob@example` but not `bob@example.com`

How can I configure ubuntu to allow logging in as both the short name and the long name.

```
[sssd]
domains = example.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/example.com]
ad_domain = example.com
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
```

The audit logs for both an unsuccesfull and a successful login

bob@example.com

```
Oct 24 20:25:59 server1 sshd[55960]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.0.2.0  user=bob@example.com
Oct 24 20:26:00 server1 sshd[55960]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.0.2.0 user=bob@example.com
Oct 24 20:26:00 server1 sshd[55960]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user bob@example.com: 17 (Failure setting user credentials)
Oct 24 20:26:02 server1 sshd[55960]: Failed password for bob@example.com from 192.0.2.0 port 9682 ssh2
Oct 24 20:26:04 server1 sshd[55960]: error: Received disconnect from 192.0.2.0 port 9682:13: Unable to authenticate [preauth]
Oct 24 20:26:04 server1 sshd[55960]: Disconnected from 192.0.2.0 port 9682 [preauth]
```

bob@example

```
Oct 24 20:26:24 server1 sshd[55975]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.0.2.0  user=bob@example
Oct 24 20:26:26 server1 sshd[55975]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.0.2.0 user=bob@example
Oct 24 20:26:27 server1 sshd[55975]: Accepted password for bob@example from 192.0.2.0 port 9693 ssh2
Oct 24 20:26:27 server1 sshd[55975]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user bob@example by (uid=0)
Oct 24 20:26:27 server1 systemd-logind[961]: New session 325 of user bob@example.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, most likely you need to set the default domain suffix under the `[sssd]` section

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sssd-user-ids.html

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
domains = example.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Then restart sssd

```
service sssd restart
```

or

```
systemctl restart sssd
```

As a side note, [make sure you don't have any comments](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/ticket/2680) in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf